# SetView in Windows Phone map with desired locations, margin and center point

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I have added a map in my Windows Phone 8 application. Now I want is to view one desired point with a center point on the map.

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="68" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                <RowDefinition Height="65" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <maps:Map x:Name="map"
                      Grid.RowSpan="5"
                          Height="800" />

<Image Source="/Assets/Images/Pin.png" Width="35" Height="55" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.RowSpan="5"
                   Canvas.ZIndex="15"/>

<Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Search" />

<Button Grid.Row="4" Content="Check" />

</Grid>
```

**View Model C#**

```
MapRectLocation zoomLocation = new MapRectLocation();
                        zoomLocation.CenterPoint = new Location() { lat = CenterLocation.Latitude, lng = CenterLocation.Longitude };
                        zoomLocation.Locationx = new Location();
                        zoomLocation.Locationx.Latitude = FirstLocation.Latitude;
                        zoomLocation.Locationx.Longitude= FirstLocation.Longitude;

                        // Calculate the other point for boundary
                        zoomLocation.Locationy= GetEqivalentPoint(CenterLocation, FirstLocation);

public Location GetEqivalentPoint(System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate CenterLocation, Location location)
        {
            var dlat = CenterLocation.Latitude - location.lat;
            var dlng = CenterLocation.Longitude - location.lng;

            Location equiPoint = new Location();
            equiPoint.lat = CenterLocation.Latitude + dlat;
            equiPoint.lng = CenterLocation.Longitude + dlng;

            return equiPoint;
        }
```

**XAML.cs Code:**

```
List<GeoCoordinate> zoomBoundaries = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
                    zoomBoundaries.Add(new GeoCoordinate(mapViewLocation.Locationx.lat, mapViewLocation.Locationx.lng));
                    zoomBoundaries.Add(new GeoCoordinate(mapViewLocation.Locationy.lat, mapViewLocation.Locationy.lng));

                    map.SetView(LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(zoomBoundaries), new Thickness(0, 150, 0, 300));
```

The map sets to desired zoom level to display that point but the problem is it does not keep the same centerpoint as earlier. I want to keep the Centerlocation as same and display FirstLocation point on the map. I am also setting margin in Setview as to keep that First location point above the 2 buttons that I have in my XAML code overlaying map.

Please let me know how to rectify this problem?

Comment: Is this really far from the original center (should not be based on your code), if not, just call SetCenter after the call to SetView, then you will be able to stay at the previous center

Comment: Yes each time this function is called the center moves away and the difference keeps on increasing. If I call SetCenter then the animation that is because of setview would look little weird... So how can i improve the functionality in the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    void SetLoc()
    {
        MyMap.Layers.Clear();
        try
        {
            // ... get the coordinates "myGeoCoordinate" 

            // Make my current location the center of the Map.
            this.MyMap.Center = myGeoCoordinate;
            this.MyMap.ZoomLevel = 12;

            // Create a small circle to mark the current location.
            Ellipse myCircle = new Ellipse();
            myCircle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            myCircle.Height = 20;
            myCircle.Width = 20;
            myCircle.Opacity = 50;

            // Create a MapOverlay to contain the circle.
            MapOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
            myLocationOverlay.Content = myCircle;
            myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            myLocationOverlay.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate;

            // Create a MapLayer to contain the MapOverlay.
            MapLayer myLocationLayer = new MapLayer();
            myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay);

            // Add the MapLayer to the Map.
            MyMap.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: The points are already added I can't clear and show them again. I need to just adjust zoom to display all the points which has gone outside the display boundaries... Adding layers again and again won't work for me..